# Como devolver un cero cuando sea null

Tags: sql

tengo una SQL con dos ficheros:

Primer fichero PRODUCTOS: (PRD) CAMPO PRODUCTO

Segundo fichero STOCK:   (PRD2) CAMPO PRODUCTO , (STOCK) CAMPO STOCK

Si hago un:

```
Select  PRD, STOCK   from PRODUCTOS inner join STOCK ON PRD=PRD2
```

Me devuelve claramente los productos que tienen stock.

Pero yo no quiero eso. Ya que hay mas registros en el fichero productos que en el stock.

Si lo hago con un left join,  Me sale null como resultado en el campo stock en las referencias que estando en el primer fichero no esta en el segundo, pero quiero que me ponga un cero.

Lo he intentado con case... y coalesce.. pero sigue saliéndome null. Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias

Comment: Como lo intentaste con coalesce?

Comment: When Coalesce(stock, 0) end Stock

Comment: No necesitas when ni end, intentalo asi: `Select prd, coalesce(stock, 0) as Stock from Productos inner join stock on prd-prd2`

Comment: Perdona mi ingenuidad, y los que tienen stock  traerá el stock?

Comment: Si, coalesce retorna el primer valor que no sea null

Comment: Genial, lo probaré mañana en el trabajo. Gracias. Mañana te digo

Comment: Perfecto funciona gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas when ni end, intentalo asi:

```
Select prd, coalesce(stock, 0) as Stock from Productos inner join stock on prd-prd2
```